# AS2: Dynamic tween identifier

Tags: animation, actionscript, actionscript-2, tween

How do i go about setting the tween identifier dynamically. I have tried eval but it says I need a variable on the left of the assignment operator. here's what I tried:

```
eval ("TweenAX" + circle.current.arrowHead.count) = new Tween(circle.current.arrowHead, "_x", mx.transitions.easing.Strong.easeOut, circle.current._x, Stage.width/2, 2, true);
eval ("TweenAY" + circle.current.arrowHead.count) = new Tween(circle.current.arrowHead, "_y", mx.transitions.easing.Strong.easeOut, circle.current._y, Stage.height/2, 2, true);
```

Cheers

Comment: Not an answer, but I suggest to have a look at [tweener](http://code.google.com/p/tweener/) which makes tweening much mor comfortable.

Comment: Hmmm...I don't like eval much. You could have an array or associative array to store your tweens. eval or not, there's always the hacky way of accessing your variables through _root. But, as @Daniel mentioned, try a better tweening library. Tweener or [TweenLite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/) are faster, lighter and easier to use than the default mx.transitions.Tween class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you are trying to achieve, but I *think* you're looking for the bracket syntax:

```
this["TweenAX" + circle.current.arrowHead.count] = new Tween(circle.current.arrowHead, "_x", mx.transitions.easing.Strong.easeOut, circle.current._x, Stage.width/2, 2, true);
this["TweenAY" + circle.current.arrowHead.count] = new Tween(circle.current.arrowHead, "_y", mx.transitions.easing.Strong.easeOut, circle.current._y, Stage.height/2, 2, true);
```

This will create two properties on `this` named `TweenAXN` and `TweenAYN` where `N` is the value of `circle.current.arrowHead.count`